# How to get unlicensed users in Microsoft GraphAPI

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any GraphApi to get a list of all unlicensed or licensed users in O365,
I have found [This link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getoffice365activationsuserdetail)
which having this report api

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail

which is returning Activated users in **CSV** format. But I need data in `List`.

Comment: As far as I know, reports API v1 returns only csv, which you need to parse. There is also a beta version of the same endpoint that can return json by specifying $format=application/json URL parameter, but it's up to you to decide if it's stable enough. It shouldn't be used in production. Beta endpoint - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/reportroot_getoffice365activationsuserdetail

Comment: @shtrule yah thanks, The beta endpoint was giving data in json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after trying many things, I found a simple way to check user license status for every user.
You have to call `user_get` API with additional property parameter `assignedLicenses` using OData `$select` query.  Since By default, only a limited set of properties are returned ( businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName ).

So for getting all user with license info you must issue `GET` request adding `$select=assignedLicenses`.

Example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,givenName,userPrincipalName,assignedLicenses,surname
```

And response will be user with given parameters such as

```
 {
        "displayName": "displayName-value",
        "givenName": "given-name",
        "surname": "surname",
        "userPrincipalName": "somedummyUserPrincipleName@onmicrosoft.com",
        "assignedLicenses": [
            {
                "disabledPlans": [],
                "skuId": "skuId-value"
            }
        ]
    }
```

After getting all user records you can check whether any user have license assigned or not.